# Arithmetic Progression in java

Tags: java

i'm just started to learn java yesterday. But, now i met difficulty to show the arithmetic progression like the display below:

```
1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

From that example, i know that every odd numbers, the numbers increment. I've tried to make it, but the display just keep showing like this:

```
2 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            for(int j = 1; j<i; j++){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

And then, i want to take the last value of it. For example, if i have row = 3, it must be value = 2.
because :

```
row   = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
value = 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4
```

Would you tell me, what line is exactly must be fix? Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you want the output to be, but in your implementation you are printing only even numbers (that's what `if (i % 2 == 0)` means), and each number `i` is printed `i-1` times.

Comment: Explain the 2 examples. The logic is hard to grasp (both number increments and occurences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey it's a representation of a sequence that grows by 2 every step.
i.e the first element is 1 which shows up one time.
the second element is 3 which shows up 3 times (`2 2 2`)
and so on and on..
so the code you need is:

```
int a = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=10;i++){
        int j=1;
        while(j<=a){
            System.out.print(i);
            j++;
        }
        a+=2;
    }
```

printing the value in a wanted row:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int rowU = in.nextInt(); // User inputs row
int row = 1; // a variable to keep track of the rows
int repeats = 1; // the number of times a value shoud appear
for(int value=1;value<=10;value++){
    int j=1;
    while(j<=repeats){
        if(row==rowU) // if we got to the wanted row
            System.out.println(value); // print the wanted value
        j++;
        row++;
    }
    repeats+=2;
}
```

There is a better, more efficient way to get the value of a wanted row:

```
int wanted_value = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(wanted_row));
```

Thanks to @saka for bringing this one up!

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Sorry for asking , how to get the last value of the loop? For example, if we had row = 5, it must be show 3 value. row = 1 2 3 4 5, value = 1 2 2 2 3 3

Comment: @BenEz You can also get `value` from `row` by `Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(row))`

Comment: @saka1029 Nice! didn't know this neat trick.. Way more efficient

Answer (score 1):

It's not about a line that is wrong, it's your approach that's a bit off. You could fix it in multiple ways. Easiest (but not most efficient) way is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            for(int j = 1; j<i; j++){
                System.out.print((i/2) + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, only the output was changed and now it works. However, iterating over 11 numbers (0-10) when you only really care about 4-5 is not necessarily the best way to go here.
It also doesn't make your code easy to understand.

Here's an alternative.

```
int amount = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < amount; j++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    amount = amount + 2;
}
```

Here you can see that the outer `for` has been changed to only take the numbers we actually care about, which means we can remove the `if` completely.
We just have to somehow decide how many times we want to execute the `print` call, which is done with the `amount` variable.

Comment: How if we want to get the last value of the loop?

Comment: You don't need two for-loops in Java 11+ for this. Just use the String.repeat(n) function. @grty The last element is of course `i = n`. If you want the last element you can have a variable outside the first for loop (in this example) that you increase (like amount) where he wrote `amount = amount + 2` -> if you increase a value and add it to itself just write += instead -> `amount += 2`

Comment: @F.Müller I'm sorry, i don't really get it. Can you describe it with source code?

Comment: @grty actually... if I'm not mistaken, you might not have to count at all to get that number because it should be the square root of row, rounded up. Also known as `(int)(Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(row)));`

Comment: @F.Müller while you're right about both, I do not like to give answers that only work on specific java versions, although I agree that it would have been worth mentioning as well. And while I completely agree about the `+=` point, I debated with myself for a good ten seconds before switching to the version I used, because I wasn't sure what would be easier to understand for a beginner, especially someone who just started learning yesterday. The `+=` might still have been the better choice though ;)

Comment: @Mark I know it is just syntactic sugar. And about the java 11 thingy, this was just meant to be a hint. Your solution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for (int i = 1, r = 1; i <= 4; ++i, r += 2)
    System.out.print((i + " ").repeat(r));
```

You can calculate `value` from `row` with this method.

[image]

```
static int value(int row) {
    return (int)Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(row));
}
```

So you can also do like this.

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 16; ++row)
    System.out.print(value(row) + " ");
```

result:

```
1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Best answer so far, but you may want to elaborate on your approach for him (he is new). Also, this does only work in Java 11+.

Answer (score 0):

`i % 2 == 0` means that the following code is only going to be executed, if `i` is even.

You could try removing the `if`, and change the second `for` to something like
`int j = 0; j < 2 * i - 1; j++`.

Comment: Sorry for asking, how to get the last value of the loop? For example, if we had row = 5, it must be show 3 value. row = 1 2 3 4 5, value = 1 2 2 2 3 3

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will do the work

```
int n=4;
int printTimes=1;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<printTimes;j++)
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    printTimes+=2;
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code.

```java
        int start = 1;
        int end = 5;
        int time = 1;

        for (int i = start,j = time; i < end; i++,j+=2) {
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                System.out.print(i+" ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should add an explanation as to what your code is doing, an answer that is just code isn't very helpful.